# Mongoexport returning more records than the specified limit

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am using `mongoexport` in my PowerShell script with the `/limit` parameter set to 100000. When executed, the result showed that it exported more than 100000.

```
& 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongoexport.exe' /uri:$DbUri /collection:$DbCollection /fields:id,detail.quantity,location_code,sku /type:csv /out:$exportFileName /limit:100000 /ssl --noHeaderLine
```

The number of records exported is 100101. I am wondering why this is the case and is there a way to prevent this?

```
2019-11-11T21:32:18.720+0000    [########################]  inv_supp  100101/100000  (100.1%)
2019-11-11T21:32:18.720+0000    exported 100101 records
```

Comment: [1] what does this have to do with powershell? [2] have you tried this in a CMD.exe shell? [3] why are you mixing `/` and `--` option delimiters? the docs seem to all show the double hyphen ...

Comment: Further, are you inserting data into the collection while exporting it at the same time?

Comment: This is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not SO.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey [1]This is a snippet of code in the powershell script I am developing. I will be doing a for loop to run the export in chunks since the collection has 23M records.  [2]Yes, I tried running it in a CMD.exe shell and it gave the same result as when run in PS. [3] Powershell does not recognize the -- option delimiters.

Comment: @cenko - thank you for the added info. it's odd that you CAN mix the two option styles. ///// have you looked at the `--%` "stop parsing" option? it may allow you to use whatever style you wish. ///// i am out of ideas, so i will go back to lurking. good luck! [*grin*]